# Using respond_with how can I flash a notice with an ajax response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, notice

The flash method only shows the message after the page reloads... what do I do to get it to appear when I'm using :remote => true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using :remote => true you are actually doing Ajax request.
in that case, the flash will not work.

What you need is to have a js function that mimics that flash message.

I usually have that: (Mootools, but you probably get the idea)

```
showMessage: function(message, style, addReload)
    {
        var class_name = style + "_message message";

        var flash = $("flash_message");

        if (flash) {
            flash.dispose();
        }

        flashElement = new Element("div", {
            id: 'flash_message'
        });
        flashElement.set('class', class_name);

        var strong = new Element('strong', { 
                                html: message
                                });

        if(addReload)
        {
            strong.adopt(
                            new Element("a", {href: window.location, html: 'Reload'})
                        );
        }

        flashElement.adopt(
                            strong
                        );


        flashElement.inject($("mainPageContainer"));
        Site.show_message();
    },
```

Whenever I use :remote => true, I have that in the js view

```
<% flash.discard %>
Dashboard.showMessage('Comment added and was sent to clients', 'notice');
```